# Where can I find a customizable arrow button?

Tags: website-design, icon

I'm implementing an up/down voting system, and I want to find a standard but sleek button with an arrow inside it that you can customize by color, arrow size etc.

Comment: Do you have photoshop?

Comment: nah, I think I'm going to default to html entities for the arrows for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing this in html and css?
Do you need the shape to adapt dynamically on site? You could use the htmlentities and get these: 
←  ↑  ⇐  ⇑
You could then change size and color with css font-size and color.
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html

Otherwise I would do as Nikhil Singh suggests. It is far easier and definitely faster to do some arrows yourself.

Comment: + it makes you feel like a roaring lion when typing by hand: `&rarr; &Rarr; &rArr;`!

Comment: @koiyu ... I still feel the rush

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue time and time again. I think it's best to make your own arrows. They're pretty basic shapes that can be constructed easily in InkScape - (which is free), or Illustrator/Corel Draw.

You can then color them to your liking, export 2 png files - one for static and one for mouse over state.

Hope this was of some help.

Peace,
Nikhil

Comment: I may suggest adding some gradients. (That's my usual suggestion for everything. :) I loooooove gradients.)